# Decoding encoded email id in python

Tags: python, email, decode

I have an email address which is encoded

```
su&#098;&#105;&#046;&#098;&#104;&#097;&#115;&#107;&#097;&#114;&#097;&#110;@in.ibm.co&#109;
```

I have to decode the above enoded and if we decode i will get this email address

```
subi.bhaskaran@in.ibm.com
```

I wrote a script for decoding but it is not working

```
from email.header import decode_header
print decode_header("""=su&#098;&#105;&#046;&#098;&#104;&#097;&#115;&#107;&#097;&#114;&#097;&#110;@in.ibm.co&#109;=""")
```

Output:

```
[('=su&#098;&#105;&#046;&#098;&#104;&#097;&#115;&#107;&#097;&#114;&#097;&#110;@in.ibm.co&#109;=', None)]
```

Which is not decoding it.

How could i decode this?

```
su&#098;&#105;&#046;&#098;&#104;&#097;&#115;&#107;&#097;&#114;&#097;&#110;@in.ibm.co&#109;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ascii HTML encoding.

```
import HTMLParser
encoded_text = 'su&#098;&#105;&#046;&#098;&#104;&#097;&#115;&#107;&#097;&#114;&#097;&#110;@in.ibm.co&#109;'
decoded_text = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(encoded_text)
```